# Adding Grand Total in R

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there any way to add the grand total row at the last as I need to know how I can get total Invoiced for all months

Note- This dataset is a data.frame and where Months are just vector names.

```
      |Invoiced_With_Writeoff|Invoiced_Without_Writeoff|Total_Invoiced
July  |         2040         |          17739          |    19779
Aug   |          371         |           2329          |     2700
Sep   |          456         |            123          |      579
Oct   |          123         |            125          |      248
Nov   |          456         |            456          |      912
```

Comment: This is more a programming question, StackOverflow probably has this answered.

Comment: colsums should help in this

Comment: `colSums` is the answer actually, I just don't think this question belong in SuperUser